# Advice or alternative to using Awk with associative array and duplicate records

Tags: awk

I started with an associative array and 2 files an awk, and I can sort of see my problem.  Where there are duplicate records, i get only 1 result.  But I would have thought the result would be the bulldog overwriting the terrier.  Why am I getting this result?

My file1.tsv is:

```
cat siamese
dog terrier
dog bulldog
snake python
```

file2.tsv is:

```
A barking dog never bites.
A cat has nine lives.
A bird in the hand is worth two in the bush.
```

My current script is:

```
FILE1="./file1.tsv"
FILE2="./file2.tsv"
awk '
  BEGIN {FS = OFS = "\t";}
  NR == FNR {kw[$1] = $2; next}
  {
    n = split(tolower($1), words, /[[:blank:]]|\.|,/)
    for (i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
      if (words[i] in kw && length(words[i]) > 2) print kw[words[i]], $1, "PHRASE"
      }
    }
' $FILE1 $FILE2 | sort -t $'\t' -k1,1 -k2  > test.tsv
```

The current output is:

```
siamese A cat has nine lives.   PHRASE
siamese A dog and a cat are friends.    PHRASE
terrier A barking dog never bites.  PHRASE
terrier A dog and a cat are friends.    PHRASE
```

But what i'm looking for is (i might not have the order right but with the two missing bulldogs:

```
siamese A cat has nine lives.   PHRASE
siamese A dog and a cat are friends.    PHRASE
bulldog A dog and a cat are friends.    PHRASE
bulldog A barking dog never bites.  PHRASE
terrier A barking dog never bites.  PHRASE
terrier A dog and a cat are friends.    PHRASE
```

Am I barking up the wrong tree with awk?   How can I achieve this?

Thanks for any help here.

Comment: You're setting the field separator to a tab (`FS = OFS = "\t";`) but input like `A cat has nine lives.` doesn't appear to be tab-separated. You should include a line that ends in `dog.` in your sample input, e.g. `I once had a dog.`, to test that `dog` is recognized as a "word" even if it's not followed by a space.

Comment: fwiw, when I run your script with your (space delimited) data I get ***no*** output; if you are getting output in your env then what we've been presented with here (data files and/or `awk` script) does not match what's in your env

Comment: and if I modify my version of `file1.tsv` to contain a tab between words then this `awk` script only generates 2 lines of output (not 4 lines as stated in the question) ... 1 line for `bulldog` and 1 line for `siamese`

Comment: also ... how do you generate `siamese A dog and a cat are friends.    PHRASE` and `terrier A dog and a cat are friends.    PHRASE` when the phrase `A dog and a cat are friends.` does not exist in `file2.tsv`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This answer uses GNU awk specifically, for arrays of arrays:

```bash
gawk '
  NR == FNR {animal[$1][$2]; next}
  {
    for (species in animal)
      if ($0 ~ species)
        for (type in animal[species])
          print type, $0, "PHRASE"
  }
' file1.tsv file2.tsv
```

Which produces

```
bulldog A barking dog never bites. PHRASE
terrier A barking dog never bites. PHRASE
siamese A cat has nine lives. PHRASE
siamese A dog and a cat are friends. PHRASE
bulldog A dog and a cat are friends. PHRASE
terrier A dog and a cat are friends. PHRASE
```

given file2.tsv containing

```
A barking dog never bites.
A cat has nine lives.
A dog and a cat are friends.
```

---

To match the **word** "dog" or "cat", we can make the regex more precise using word boundaries:

```
      if (tolower($0) ~ "\\<" species "\\>")
```

That way, you won't match against a line like:

```
My book is dogeared! What a catastrophe!
```

Answer (score 3):

(Reusing glenn jackman's correction your second file)

You can use any awk this way:

```
awk 'BEGIN{OFS="\t"}
FNR==NR {animals[$1,$2]; idx[$1]; next}
{
    for(i=1; i<=NR; i++) {
        if ($i in idx) {
            for (ci in animals) {
                split(ci, seps, SUBSEP)
                if (seps[1]==$i)
                    print seps[2], $0, "PHRASE"
            }    
        }
    }
}' file_1 file_2
```

Prints:

```
terrier A barking dog never bites.  PHRASE
bulldog A barking dog never bites.  PHRASE
siamese A cat has nine lives.   PHRASE
terrier A dog and a cat are friends.    PHRASE
bulldog A dog and a cat are friends.    PHRASE
siamese A dog and a cat are friends.    PHRASE
```

(Note that the order is likely different than the file order since awk arrays are unordered.)

Or here is a Ruby:

```
ruby -lane '
BEGIN{animals=Hash.new { |h, k| h[k] = []} }
if $<.file.lineno == $<.lineno then
    animals[$F[0]] << $F[1]
    next
end
a_set=animals.keys.to_set if $<.file.lineno==1 && $.>1
$F.to_set.intersection(a_set).each{|word| 
        animals[word].each{|m| 
        puts "#{m}\t#{$_}\tPHRASE"} 
    }
' file_1 file_2
```

Prints:

```
terrier A barking dog never bites.  PHRASE
bulldog A barking dog never bites.  PHRASE
siamese A cat has nine lives.   PHRASE
siamese A dog and a cat are friends.    PHRASE
terrier A dog and a cat are friends.    PHRASE
bulldog A dog and a cat are friends.    PHRASE
```

The Ruby maintains file order. It *might* be faster since it uses sets to skip non matching words in each line.